# Ошибки в консоли git

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

При попытке запушить проект на репозиторий в GitHub возникают такие ошибки:

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/StepanSnigur/jsShop.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

При попытке push не открыты редакторы или другие инструменты редактирования.

Вот скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `git pull` сначала сделайте

Comment: а если сначала сделать pull?

Comment: Написано же прямо в тексте, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Попробуйте перевести текст сообщения хотя бы google-translate'ом. Если останутся непонятные моменты - дополните вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка возникала из-за конфликта файлов README, она решилась простым снятием галочки при создании репозитория